# No "Hyper-V" in Win Features to install after installing VS2013 Preview

Tags: hyper-v, visual-studio-2013

On a Windows 8 machine with VS Express 2010, VS 2012, I've installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Preview.

In the end of the installation, an error message appears, giving me this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to activate Hyper-V.

So i entered BIOS, I found a similar option for enabling Virtualization, and set it to Enable.

After finishing restart,  I downloaded coreinfo.exe, opened the console as Admin, and checked for asterisk in the row where it said I should check. So there was, which means my computer supports SLAT.

When I go to Control Panel -> Programs -> Windows Features on/off, there is no Hyper-V there as is shown in the link that there will be, and I should select it and press OK to install/activate it.

Will this be fixed by reinstalling Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Preview now?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running Windows 8 Pro 64-bit as the Hyper-V feature is a Pro Edition feature.